# HTML object tag for Java to target specific version

Tags: java, html, applet, internet-explorer-11, object-tag

I am using HTML object tag for displaying Java applet, which runs only on Java 6 update 23 on Internet Explorer 11 (IE 11).  Is it possible to target specific version of Java using `object` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE11 crashing with that 6u23 JRE plugin must upgrade to higher version..

run the IE in compatibility mode only workaround..

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `param` with the required version in it.  For example:

```html
<object classid="clsid:XXXX" codebase="http://url_place_holder..."
  width="200" height="200">
    <param name="code" value="YourApplet">
    <param name="java_version" value="1.6.23*">
</object>
```

*Note*: The `classid` should also point to the JRE that you are looking to use in order to maintain backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really practicable in this day and age.  Any attempt for an applet to load an outdated VM will lead to severe security warnings, even if the applet is digitally signed and sand-boxed.